# Makefile: no such file or directory '-c'

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have the following items in a folder:

```
Makefile    run.sh      tester.c    tester.h
```

My makefile is as follows:

```
CC=gcc

tester: tester.o
    ${CC} tester.o -o tester

tester.o: tester.c
    ${CC} - c tester.c
```

When I run it on the terminal i get the following message

```
gcc - c tester.c
clang: error: -E or -x required when input is from standard input
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'c'
make: *** [tester.o] Error 1
```

I am not sure what exactly am I missing. The code file just has a main function returning 1.

Comment: There is an extra space in `${CC} - c tester.c`. It should be `-c`

Comment: Would advise to also include `tester.h` as a dependency to `tester.o`, otherwise a change on this header file will not trigger a compilation of this module.

Comment: This is just a typo.  You have `- c` where you need `-c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tester.o: tester.c
    ${CC} - c tester.c
```

There should not be a space between the `-` and `c`.